# URLs in chat room descriptions don't get linkified nicely

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, hyperlinks

While viewing [Shog's chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3435/shog9) to make myself feel like less of a nerd<sup>1</sup>, I noticed a promising link in the description of one of the rooms he was listed as being in:

[image: screenshot]

Naturally I clicked it, and it took me to `https://i.stack.imgur.com...`.  The real link (which shows up in the title text if you hover over it) is [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzBew.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzBew.jpg).  A minor annoyance, to be sure, but probably easy to fix.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I wanted to make sure he had more rep than me, because no one else I saw in the [Android Town Hall Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1921) did.  Ugh.  I need to offer more bounties or get a life or something.</sub>

Comment: Also for anyone using the Chrome 16 beta, that first backticked URL should show an ellipsis at the end.  This version has an incredible number of bugs.

Comment: Yep, that's *my* imaeg macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't get linkified *at all*. I don't know which functionality of your browser turned that into a link, but it wasn't us.

We only linkify the room description on the room's actual live chat page.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  I really hate this latest version of Chrome.