# Plain links don't get linkified in the stars tab of the chat room info?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

Viewing the [stars tab for Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta/?tab=stars), the first item is a link to Jeff's blog about his leaving, but it doesn't get linkified like it does in the normal list. It should display as:

> [codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html)

Am I expected to actually copy-paste a link? That's a lot of effort, you know.

Here's an image, since apparently this is not an issue for everyone:

[image: links-not-clickable]

Comment: I'm confused. You mean you're having trouble doing this? --> [Farewell Stack Exchange](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html)

Comment: @Robert: Did you look at the page? Plain links which start with just `http://` appear as plain text, they don't become actual hyperlinks.

Comment: It looks like a link to me.

Comment: @Robert: Can you click it?

Comment: Of course.  It takes me to Jeff's blog post.

Comment: I see this as well, FF10 on Ubuntu 10.10.  Possibly status-bydesign if related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115101/154510.  Any chance you have a linkifier extension like I do in Chrome, @Robert?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you actually on the stars page, and not looking at the stars list in the sidebar?

Comment: I'm not in Chrome or FireFox; I'm in IE8.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe this is similar to the [block quote issue in transcripts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119257/quote-formatting-not-applied-in-chat-transcripts), which makes me rage, but we'll see.

Comment: @TimStone: No, I'm in the Tavern.  Why would you need this in the archives?  Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V.

Comment: Interesting; I *thought* we ran out auto-linkify code over that, but I'll check in the morning.

Comment: @Marc: Did you ever check that morning?

Comment: @animuson I did, but I was somewhat distracted by a rogue server burning up memory ;p taking a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me...

(coughs quietly)

Comment: Cough more quietly please, it's too not-subtle.